# How to add a bar like "Congrats ... – learn more" of this site?

Tags: html, css, ajax

I think the floating bar saying
"Congrats, you've gained the privilege – talk in chat learn more" 
looks so cool, and so neat to for reporting status. How to add one to my own site please?

Comment: Don't forget that the HTML and JavaScript are there for all to see. :)

Comment: You may want to tag your question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at the StackOverflow source, the way I imagine it would be done is as follows:

Add a div called notify (or whatever else you want to call it) to the top of your page; something like this:

```
#notify{
width: 100%;
height: 30px;

position: absolute;

top: 0;

display: none;

z-index: 500;
}
```

Then use the jQuery slideUp and slideDown methods (or however else you want to) to animate it when a new notification is found via ajax. (you could use mootools or another JavaScript library if you wanted to)

( http://api.jquery.com/slideUp, http://api.jquery.com/slideDown, http://api.jquery.com/animate, and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ )

Comment: thank you. I went for jGrowl instead, whose message box looks even more elegant. :D

Answer (score 0):

View > Page Source.

This is the div box that contains it (or at least appears to contain it).  Seems that they are using jQuery with an accordion style action.

```
<div id="notify-container"></div>
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/